# Trouble restoring database using T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
backup database Clinical_Data_Extension to disk='c:\Clinical_Data_Extension_full.bak'
restore filelistonly from disk='c:\Clinical_Data_Extension_full.bak'
restore database Clinical_Data from disk='c:\Clinical_Data_Extension_full.bak'
with move 'Clinical_Data_Extension' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Clinical_Data.mdf',
move 'Clinical_Data_Extension_log' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Clinical_Data.ldf',
REPLACE
```

Error:

```
Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Logical file 'Clinical_Data_Extension' is not part of database 'Clinical_Data'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Yet for some reason the following identical code works fine:

```
backup database Clinical_Data to disk='c:\Clinical_Data_full.bak'
restore filelistonly from disk='c:\Clinical_Data_full.bak'
restore database Clinical_Data_Extension from disk='c:\Clinical_Data_full.bak'
with move 'Clinical_Data' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Clinical_Data_Extension.mdf',
move 'Clinical_Data_log' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Clinical_Data_Extension.ldf',
REPLACE
```

Basically, what I am doing is creating database "Clinical_Data_Extension" and doing work on it. Once I am done, I have a script for removing "Clinical_Data", and then I use the script which I mentioned first to restore "Clinical_Data" using data from "Clinical_Data_Extension" essentially overwriting "Clinical_Data". However for some reason the first script gives me an error and the second does not yet they are totally identical.
Why do you think this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

No, the second code is not identical. After

```
move
```

it says

```
'Clinical_Data'
```

not

```
'Clinical_Data_Extension'
```

.That is crucial. It is the Logical Name of the data container inside the backup.

```
USE master
GO
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
   FROM disk='c:\Clinical_Data_Extension_full.bak'
```

gives You the precise Logical Names. Logical Names and Database Names do *not* need to be of the same convention. The Logical Name for the data container in 'Clinical_Data_Extension_full.bak' could be 'Clinical_Data' as in the other backup. The error states that Your specified Logical Name is not present in 'c:\Clinical_Data_Extension_full.bak'.

The same mixup can happen with the log container.

Comment: Thanks for answering Der U. Making those changes does allow the code to compile, but it does not do what I need. The reason why I used "Clinical_Data_Extension" in the first code is because I need to restore the Database with the information in "Clinical_Data_Extension" because that database will have the updated data while "Clinical_Data" contains the old data. My clients will be copying the database "Clinical_Data" to "Clinical_Data_Extension" and changing that database. Once they are done, I want to delete "Clinical_Data", and replace it with "Clinical_Data_Extension" using my first routine

Comment: what changes did you make? what does "changing the database" mean?